# Amazon SES Connection

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am trying to use Amazon SES mail service. I have configured settings properly, and with the credentials it is working in one of our network machine, but in other it is not working,  alwayz gives ConnectException

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com, port: 25;nested exception is:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: any firewall you need open on the problem machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your security groups and make sure SMTP port is open to this network or device.